# Is it possible to show / hide html content using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, pagespeed

I'm building a website that needs to be built for optimal speed performance and work on both regular desktop or mobile.

I'm interested in in going further than hiding certain elements using media queries and css - instead I am looking to load completely different HTML depending on the device.

Is there a simple solution to pick which elements to load using JavaScript or jQuery that I can add site wide?

Comment: just make some conditions using the user agent. And you don't need to hide them, you can just render them initially after checking the user agent

Comment: I like where you are going with this. Can you explain just a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using completely different html pages and use redirect based on the width of the screen.

Answering your question is yes you can do this using query or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to detect the user agent making the request and serve back different files based on the value.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the basic adaptive design approach. I'm looking for more of a responsive design approach but instead of using CSS to show and hide I want to load sections that are appropriate for the device.

Comment: How can you determine what the appropriate content for the device is without first determining the device?

If you want to filter by resolution that's different, use media queries or javascript.